# java creating an iterator for a custom data structure

Tags: java, interface, iterator, abstract-class

So here's what I have:

- 1 interface called Set
- 1 abstract class which implements set
- 2 classes which extend the abstract class, called `ArraySet` and `ListSet`

So in Set, I state `Iterator <String> iterator();` and then in my 2 nonabstract classes, I have nested classes which are called `ArrayIterator` and `ListIterator`, which implement the iterator's functionality. But the compiler complains that `ArraySet` and `ListSet` must 
implement `Set.iterator()`. How do I make it so that the compiler recognizes that `ArrayIterator` and `ListIterator` are the implementations of `Set.iterator()`?

So it looks like

```
interface Set extends Iterable< String > {  
...  
Iterator< String > iterator(); }  




class ArraySet extends AbstractClass {  
 ...  
    class ArrayIterator implements Iterator< String > { ... }  
 ...  
}
```

Comment: Can you post the definitions?

Comment: Did you remember to include a method called `iterator` that returned an instance of the appropriate iterator?

Comment: What do you mean by 'nested classes' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `Set.iterator()` in your non-abstract classes `ArraySet` and `ListSet`, ie:

In `ArraySet`:

```
Iterator<String> iterator() {
    // do something, probably return ArrayIterator ?
}
```

In `ListSet`:

```
Iterator<String> iterator() {
    // do something, probably return ListIterator ?
}
```

Also, I assume that both `ArrayIterator` and `ListIterator` implements `Iterator`

Comment: ok. before I was trying to define iterator() inside the nested classes ArrayIterator and ListIterator, I defined it outside and it seems to work. thanks

Comment: No problem. It's both `ArraySet` and `ListSet` that needs to implement `iterator()`, not `ArrayIterator` nor `ListIterator`. On a side note, if you find it working, you should accept the solution

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question. But just for the sake of knowledge you may want to know what is an internal iterator and what is an external iterator?
Ref: Design Pattern book by GoF

[or otherwise have a look at this](http://www.oodesign.com/iterator-pattern.html)